# Como faço para dar um echo sem quebra de linha?

Tags: batch

Eu tenho esta linha no arquivo `.bat`

```
for /L %%a in (1,1,3)DO echo %%a
```

Que imprime:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

mas eu quero que imprima na mesma linha, desta forma:

> 1 2 3

Answer (score 4):

Um ótimo *reparo técnico* <sup>1</sup> é usar o `set` com o parâmetro `/P` para evitar a quebra de linha.

Os dois *batches* a seguir produzem o efeito desejado:

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,3)DO echo|set /p="%%a "
```

e

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,3)DO <nul set /p="%%a "
```

O `/p` normalmente é usado para *input* com um *prompt*, e por isso não quebra nenhuma linha. Combinando o *input* com uma entrada artificial, que vem de um `echo` com *pipe* no primeiro exemplo e um `nul` no lugar do *stdin* do segundo, temos o efeito de mostrar o *prompt* sem quebrar linhas, e sem esperar o *input* do usuário.

A segunda opção aparentemente tem maior performance, o que pode ser avaliado com testes mais extensivos (loops maiores, por exemplo).

<sub><sup>1. Gambiarra</sup></sub>